# SQLite query with literal values

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, in-subquery

I have a 2 tables A and B in SQLite

**A:**

```
Name|Badge
----------
ABC |X
XYZ |Y
```

**B:**

```
ListCode |Badges
--------------------
V        |'X','Y','Z'
```

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE BADGE IN (SELECT BADGES FROM B WHERE LISTCODE = 'V');
```

The problem is SELECT IN doesnt seem to work like that with literal csv from another table. 
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The moral of the story here is to not store CSV data as you have been doing.  This answers assumes that you are actually storing *unquoted* CSV data, i.e. this:

```
X,Y,Z
```

That being said, you can workaround this by using the following query:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.BADGE = B.BADGES OR
       B.BADGES LIKE A.BADGE || ',%' OR
       B.BADGES LIKE '%,' || A.BADGE || ',%' OR
       B.BADGES LIKE '%,' || A.BADGE
WHERE
    B.BADGES IS NOT NULL
```

Here is a demo of the above query.  It is in MySQL because Rextester does not support SQLite but the logic and data are identical.

## Demo

Comment: I actually have an option of not storing quoted values in there. But I want the php client code to be as simple as possible to call. If I had the possibility of changing the insert into table B (but it still has to be a single row), what would be the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: I don't know your PHP code or even PHP.  I think storing CSV is a bad idea, and quoting the values is a particularly bad idea.

Comment: @user8621037 I added a demo to the query.  This should at least let you function while you work on cleaning up your data model.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it. I might do as you suggested and just clean up the table structure. The problem is, this is a legacy system and some of this stuff hits code elsewhere which makes it a little problematic to change.

Comment: simpler: `','||badges||',' LIKE '%,'||badge||',%'`

Comment: @CL. Simpler but more concatenations and less efficient.  Best would be to avoid the CSV altogether.

Comment: @CL. Simpler but more concatenations and less efficient.  Best would be to avoid the CSV altogether.